# What is the best way to initialise static members before constructing objects in Java?

Tags: java, oop, refactoring, settings

I am currently in the process of refactoring the code I wrote for a text/console version of the Mastermind board game. I am a bit stuck with how to best approach improving this section my `GameLogic` class.

```
public GameLogic(GameSettings gameSettings)
{
    // ..other stuff..

    // initialise static members
    Board.setTotalRows(gameSettings.getNumOfGuesses());
    Board.setTotalColums(gameSettings.getCodeLength());

    // InputBoard and OutputBoard extends the abstract class Board
    inputBoard = new InputBoard();
    outputBoard = new OutputBoard();
}
```

What I am trying to do is set the static values of `totalRows` and `totalColumns` in the `Board` class BEFORE constructing the `inputBoard` and `outputBoard` objects. The reason why I want to do this is because I need to have these values present when constructing instances extending Board (an abstract class). The reason why I am making these values static is because they should be the same across all instances extending from `Board` and so that I can do something like `Board.getTotalColumns()` throughout the application.

The reason why I think this is suspiciously bad is because it would be possible to declare `inputBoard` or `outputBoard` without first setting the static member variables and of course it would also be possible to accidentally set the values of the static member later on to any arbitrary value.

Another approach I thought of was to make the getters in GameSettings public and static so that I could do something like this instead:

```
public abstract class Board 
{
    private static final int totalColumns = GameSettings.getCodeLength();
    private static final int totalRows = GameSettings.getNumOfGuesses();

    // other stuff...
}
```

This would allow me to avoid using setters and the problems associated with using them as listed above. But wouldn't this defeat the purpose of instantiating a `GameSettings` object?

What do you think are better alternatives to approach this?

Comment: Don't have static in the first place and also don't do `Board.getTotalColumns()`. That kind of static use is against all OOP ideas. Your `Board` constructor needs a `GameSettings` object. And classes that intereact with the `Board` need that in their constructor and so on.

Comment: @zapl Thanks for the comment. I thought static is useful when you know that the value of something is not going to change across instances. Are you suggesting instead I do something like:  `inputBoard = new InputBoard(gameSettings.getCodeLength(), gameSettings.getNumOfGuesses());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert on design pattern. I would try something like below -

**Board.java**

```
abstract class Board {
    private final GameSettings gameSettings;

    Board(GameSettings gameSettings) {
        this.gameSettings = gameSettings;
    }
    public int getTotalColumns() {
        return gameSettings.getCodeLength();
    }
    public int getTotalRows() {
        return gameSettings.getNumOfGuesses();
    }

    //Other abstract methods
}
```

**InputBoards .java**

```
class InputBoards extends Board {
    InputBoards(GameSettings gameSettings) {
        super(gameSettings);
    }
}
```

**OutputBoards .java**

```
class OutputBoards extends Board {
    OutputBoards(GameSettings gameSettings) {
        super(gameSettings);
    }
}
```

**GameSettings .java**

```
class GameSettings {
    public int getCodeLength() {
        //return your value;
    }
    public int getNumOfGuesses() {
        //return your value;
    }
}
```

Now I would do -

```
public GameLogic(GameSettings gameSettings) {
    inputBoard = new InputBoard(gameSettings);
    outputBoard = new OutputBoard(gameSettings);
}
```